# Find locator in selenium by name with a parameter

Tags: java, selenium

I'm struggling to figure out how to find an element by its name, but not by multiplying elements locators  but to create one for its kind and passing a parameter. E.g there's a page with 10 buttons 'Add to Cart' for different items ('Laptop  A', 'Laptop  b','Laptop  c', etc), so instead of creating 3 different elements I want to have one, something like >> 
`webElement elementByName(String itemName) = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@button='add to cart' and @title = '" +  itemName+ "']"))`
Does anything like this exist in selenium? I'm new to selenium and could not find anything similar. thanks

Comment: Please make it human readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Before I share the 'answer', I would like to point out the following:

**Some things to note**

The xpath that you need to provide is nothing special to Selenium. It is a W3C standard.
https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-datamodel-31-20170321/

If you're using Chrome, before even attempting to use it in Selenium, you can first test out your xpath by going to Developer Tools (F12) and pressing 'CTRL+F', and typing in the xpath in the search box that appears.

If your xpath matches an element, it will be highlighted in yellow. If that xpath works, it should also work if you pass that same xpath into Selenium, unless there are other reasons such as framework being used, etc. For instance, Shadow DOM xpaths are not especially friendly to use.

**Searching by Visible Text**

Going by your example of `Laptop A; Laptop B; Laptop C`, if you want to find the element based on visible text, then you can use the `text()` function (that xpath provides).

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Laptop A']");   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Laptop B']");
```

With the above in mind, you can thus put the strings `A` and `B` into an array and loop through them if you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size; i++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Laptop " + arr[i] + "']");   
}
```

Additionally, you can also use the `contains` function that sort of acts like a regex:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Laptop')]");
```

This will match anything that has a visible text of `Laptop`, i.e. `Laptop A`, `Laptop b`, `This is a Laptop`, etc.

**EDIT: based on comments below**

```
public WebElement selectButtonByName(String name){
     return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@button='add to cart' and @title = '" + name+ "']"));
}
```

And then by using it:

```
WebElement tvElement = selectButtonByName("TV").click();
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I dont think this was exactly what I was looking for. What I meant is more like only one webElement (or a method) where I can pass a parameter. Let's say, for multiple items of different name, but where button is of the same class. Is there anything like this? 
So  e.g.
WebElement selectButtonByName(String name) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@button='add to cart' and @title = '" +  itemName+ "']")).
And I can use it everywhere the div[@button  matches and where name is what I pass > selectButtonByName("TV"); selectButtonByName("Iron"); selectButtonByName("mobile")

Comment: Yes, you can ahead to do it like that. Check out my modified answer below to see if that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you need to wrap your the findElement method and create a custom method for it, best practice is always wrap and have custom methods for all driver related actions, which will help you on the long run and will be scalable. here is an oversimplified example:

first step is to wrap your driver:

```
public class MyDriver {
    //initialise your webdriver, the way you see fit and lets assume you name it 
      myDriver;

    // create your custom find element method
    public WebElement findElement(final By by){
      return myDriver.findElement(by);
    }

    // create a method which uses the findElemet method and passes the webelement to next 
    // method
    public WebElement click(final By bys){
      return clickElement(findElement(bys);
    }

    // this is the click method, which you can use directly for webelements
    public WebElement clickElement(final WebElement element){
      Actions action = new Action(myDriver);
      action.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
      return element;
    }
}


// Now that we have our basic wrapper, lets use it for your needs:

public class YourTestCase {
    MyDriver driver = new MyDriver(); //this is not best way to do it, just an example

    // now you can use whatever parameter you like and add it with custom xpath logic
    private WebElement myElementFinder(final String parameter){
      return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@button='add to cart'][@title = '" +  
        parameter + "']"));
    }

    // here you click the button, by passing the passing only
    public void clickButton(final String buttonText){
      driver.click(myElementFinder(buttonText))
    }
}
```

By taking this logic you can build a solid framework, hope it helps, comment if need more explanation, cheers.